# AngularJS - When working with ui-router, views are not cleaned before re-appear

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on an admin panel in AngularJS. The panel includes 4 tabs, each contains a table (of users etc.) and pressing on a row will lead to a specific object screen (e.g: all user details, includes those which not appear in table).

Everything is working OK, beside one thing. I press on a row in the users table, I get the user screen. When pressing back and than pressing another user row, I can see for a seconds (until data is received from server) the previous user data.

This is what I have in my HTML:

```
    <div class="span12" ui-view >
        <!--PAGE CONTENT BEGINS-->

        <!--PAGE CONTENT ENDS-->
    </div><!--/.span-->
```

And in my controllers all the transition looks like (for example):

```
    $state.transitionTo('userDetails', {userId: id});
```

Is there any way to reload completeley the HTML so the user won't see previous data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem maybe due to model data, not the html detail view. The object that you are binding to the detail view, only gets updated when you return data from server, till that time it contains the last binded object value and hence you see the old values.